# Can't get ul to stay open using transition-delay

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

[This page](https://www.themigrantproject.org/), on the top right, you'll see "English" if you hover over it you'll see a list of languages. You don't have time to get to the last language, the popup disappears. Basically this `ul` opens when you hover over `#lang-select`

```
#lang-select.header .block-content ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    margin: 0;
    background: #FFF;
}
```

I tried adding

```
#lang-select.header .block-content ul {
    transition-delay: 3s;
    transition-property: background;
}
```

also, I tried `transition-property: padding;` Also I tried applying `transition-delay` to `#lang-select` directly, did not work

Comment: and hover to ul too

Comment: @TemaniAfif Maybe I'm blind, I searched the entire CSS in chrome dev tools and also searched all the sources, couldn't find a `hover` applied to `#lang-select`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the z-index. The wrapper is going over the drop down menu so once your cursor moves from the header to the wrapper it thinks your hovering over the wrapper rather than the languages.
In the css add

```
#header {
    z-index: 1000
}
```

Comment: How can you find this stuff? And I got a downvote and a close vote for not following the guidelines, regardless of what guidelines I must follow, I don't think I have the slightest chance of detecting this on my own. A popup is closing fast on hover, the logical thing to do is to add a delay. Wow, thank you Sir, for real. Just for reference, I asked on reddit webdev, and css subredits, which have like 100k users combined, no one answered.

Comment: No problem. It stumped me for a bit. I think people weren't figuring it out because we don't know how the drop down is working. There's no :hover selector so I'm assuming it's JS but you didn't include the JS function. If you included it in the question it probably wouldn't have gotten a downvote.